# Android launch your app based on user location

Tags: android, gps, broadcast, geofencing

Is it possible to launch an app depending on the user location. I want the app to start only when I enter certain location say my office. I m aware about services running in background but I dont want my app to continuously check for location and  deplete the battery.

Is it possible to register for some sort of geo-fencing broadcast ?

Answer (score 2):

You can [Create and Monitor Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) with a standard Google API.

However, if you want to know if you've arrived at your office, I think a better and more battery-friendly way would be to see if you're connected to the office Wifi network.